# kdeplot produces unexpected results

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, kdeplot

I created a simple seaborn kde plots and wonder whether this is a bug.

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.kdeplot(np.array([1,2]), cmap="Reds",  shade=True,  bw=0.01)
sns.kdeplot(np.array([2.4,2.5]), cmap="Blues", shade=True,  bw=0.01)
plt.show()
```

The blue and red lines show the kde's of 2 points. If the points are close together, the densities are much narrower compared to the points being further apart. I find this very counter intuitive, at least to the extent that can be seen. I am wondering whether this might be a bug. I also could not find a resource describing how the densities are computed from a set of given points. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Plot shows the result of the above code]

Comment: Dear JohanC, thanks for your reply! My problem is: Why do 2 separate points yield a result with two broad bumps, while 2 points close together yield 2 narrow peaks. May understanding of the method was: Each point is represented by a gaussian distribution (bump) and all these contributions add up to become the finals probability density. But then I would expect that the two closer points do not get a much narrower distribution than the two more stanstant points.

Comment: For both lines I specified the same bw factor so why does the effect depend on the distance?

Comment: Many tanks! This creates that output that I expected from the very beginning. Somehow I am still surprised why the data is scaled. I would not have expected this from my understanding of a kde. I thought every data point simply gets a gaussian assigned and the sum of all gaussians is the result without some hidden scaling of the bw. I wounder what the reason is, that the bw is scaled. Are there kde producing libraries that do not skale kde? Many thanks again.

Comment: I understand that in principle bw_method=0.01/np.std(data1) solves the problem. With one exception. I want to plot kde for data that in some cases can consist of a single point. Then I would expect simply one gaussian bump. But I get the error message that the std cannot be computed. Well, this is consitent with the behaviour of scipy.stats.gaussian_kde which needs the std to compute the bw. To avoid this problem, I would be interested in a kde plotter that does not need the std in the first place. Then I could also use it to plot a single bump for a singel data point.

Comment: [kde] as a tag refers to the desktop environment, doesn't refer to kernel density estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bw_method=` (called `bw=` in older versions), is directly passed to [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). The docs there write *"If a scalar, this will be used directly as `kde.factor`"*. The explanation of `kde.factor` tells *"The square of `kde.factor` multiplies the covariance matrix of the data in the kde estimation."* So, it is a kind of scaling factor. If still more details are needed, you could dive into [scipy's source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.0/scipy/stats/_kde.py#L41-L638), or into the research papers referenced in the docs.

If you really want to counter the scaling, you could divide it away: `sns.kdeplot(np.array(data), ..., bw_method=0.01/np.std(data))`.

Or you could create your own version of a gaussian kde, with a bandwidth in data coordinates.  It just sums some [gauss curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and normalizes (total area under the curve should be 1) via dividing by the number of curves.

Here is some example code, with kde curves for 1, 2 or 20 input points:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def gauss(x, mu=0.0, sigma=1.0):
    return np.exp(-((x - mu) / sigma) ** 2 / 2) / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))

def kde(xs, data, sigma=1.0):
    return gauss(xs.reshape(-1, 1), data.reshape(1, -1), sigma).sum(axis=1) / len(data)

sns.set()
sigma = 0.03
xs = np.linspace(0, 4, 300)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))

data1 = np.array([1, 2])
kde1 = kde(xs, data1, sigma=sigma)
ax.plot(xs, kde1, color='crimson', label=f'dist of 1, σ={sigma}')
ax.fill_between(xs, kde1, color='crimson', alpha=0.3)

data2 = np.array([2.4, 2.5])
kde2 = kde(xs, data2, sigma=sigma)
ax.plot(xs, kde2, color='dodgerblue', label=f'dist of 0.1, σ={sigma}')
ax.fill_between(xs, kde2, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.3)

data3 = np.array([3])
kde3 = kde(xs, data3, sigma=sigma)
ax.plot(xs, kde3, color='limegreen', label=f'1 point, σ={sigma}')
ax.fill_between(xs, kde3, color='limegreen', alpha=0.3)

data4 = np.random.normal(0.01, 0.1, 20).cumsum() + 1.1
kde4 = kde(xs, data4, sigma=sigma)
ax.plot(xs, kde4, color='purple', label=f'20 points, σ={sigma}')
ax.fill_between(xs, kde4, color='purple', alpha=0.3)

ax.margins(x=0)  # remove superfluous whitespace left and right
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)  # let the plot "sit" onto y=0
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: kde curves with bandwidth in data coordinates]